# External E-Mail Address - Send through Gmail | How does Google bypass SPF records?

Tags: dns, gmail

Google's Gmail allows you to add your own custom email address e.g. (address@domain.com), so that you can receive and also send email under that address.

However, I have SPF records set up which are supposed to only allow a sender from my server's IP.

Does this mean that the e-mail sent from my custom email address via Google's servers is likely to be marked as spam?

Are there any IPs I should add to the SPF records for the domain?

Comment: Do you mean SPF records?

Comment: Oops, yea. Sorry about that (wrote this q. at 3 am) :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google cannot bypass SPF records, though email servers could be configured to "trust" email from google despite SPF records stating they should not.

However, you cannot control this.

You can however [add Google](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=178723&topic=2759192&ctx=topic) to your SPF TXT record:

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all
```